# Passing php string of a friend's name to javascript function

Tags: php, javascript, facebook-graph-api, posts

I'm trying to pass a php string to a javascript function. The php portion looks like this:

```
<?php
   foreach ($friends as $key => $friend) {
   // Extract the pieces of info we need from the requests above
   $id = assertNumeric(idx($friend, 'id'));
   $name = idx($friend, 'name');
   // Here we link each friend we display to their profile
   echo('
     <li>
     <a href="#" onclick="window.open(\'http://www.facebook.com/' . $id . '\')">
     <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/' . $id . '/picture?type=square" alt="' . $name . '">'. $name . '
    </a>
    <form>
    <input type="button" value="Meet" onclick="postMeet(. $name.)"/>
    </form>
    </li>');
    }
?>
```

The javascript function looks like this. It works perfectly if I pass either $key or $id to the function but not passing $name. Anyone got any ideas? I'm pretty new to php and javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function postMeet(key)
{
        var met = 'Met ';
        var body = met + ' '+ key;
        FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { message: body }, function(response) {
               if (!response || response.error) {
               alert(response[0]);
               alert('Error occured');
               } else {
               alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
               }
               });           
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are three things to consider in your `echo` statement:

1. `$name` is a string that you're going to embed as a *string literal* inside the JavaScript in the `onclick` attribute of your HTML, so where you're passing it into your `postMeet` function, you must put quotes around it. JavaScript allows string literals to be quoted with either `'` or `"`, as long as they're balanced. Since we're quoting the `onclick` attribute with `"` (because HTML doesn't allow `'`), easiest to use `'` to delimit the JavaScript string. So: Put `'` around it.
2. The `postMeet` call is inside an HTML attribute (`onclick`), which means that when the markup is being read, it's read as HTML text. Consequently, you must ensure that any characters that are special to HTML (e.g., primarily `<` and `&`, plus in this case `"` because you've used `"` as the delimiter for your `onclick` attribute) are encoded correctly as `&lt;`, `&amp;`, and `&quot;`. PHP provides the `htmlspecialchars` function to do that. Maybe you're thinking "but `$name` will never have a `<` in it". That's how bugs show up. Get in the habit of fully encoding these things, and you won't forget when you're outputting something more interesting. Besides, people fill in all kinds of nonsense for the "name" field in databases.
3. Inside a JavaScript string literal, the backslash and whatever kind of quote you used to delimit the string (e.g., `'` or `"`) **must** be escaped (with a backslash). So you have to consider what may be in `$name` or better yet, fully defend yourself. The string literal `'T.J. Crowder'` is valid, but the string literal `'Gerard 't Hooft'` results in a syntax error because the `'` in `'t Hooft` is not escaped. It must be written either `"Gerard 't Hooft"` (delimiting with double quotes) or `'Gerard \'t Hooft'` (escaping the single quote). PHP provides a handy function, [`addslashes`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php), that will insert backslashes prior to `'`, `"`, `\`, and the null byte.

So putting that all together, we have to wrap some kind of quote around the variable's value when we output it to `postMeet`, we have to encode special HTML characters, and we have to ensure quotes and such are escaped with backslashes:

```
//                +--- start string literal with single quote
//                |
//                vv
onclick="postMeet(\''. addslashes(htmlspecialchars($name)) .'\')"
//                     ^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^            ^^
//                          |            |                   |
//  escape ", ', and \ -----+            |                   |
//           encode special HTML chars --+                   |
//                    end literal with single quote ---------+
```

E.g.:

```
echo('
  <li>
  <a href="#" onclick="window.open(\'http://www.facebook.com/' . $id . '\')">
  <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/' . $id . '/picture?type=square" alt="' . $name . '">'. $name . '
 </a>
 <form>
 <input type="button" value="Meet" onclick="postMeet(\''. addslashes(htmlspecialchars($name)) .'\')"/>
 </form>
 </li>');
```

It's important to remember the three layers of interpretation going on: PHP is interpreting your PHP code and outputting markup to an HTML page; the browser is interpreting the HTML markup, including the content of the `onclick` attribute; and the JavaScript interpreter interprets the string content of the `onclick` attribute (the browser passes it on when the click occurs), which must be valid JavaScript code.

Here's a more isolated example that's easy to copy and paste into a test page. Use "view source" on the test page to see what the browser saw, and of course click the `div` to see that everything worked correctly:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>PHP Escape Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    $stuff = "Gerard 't Hooft says <<\"theoretical physics is FUN & a great way to aid humankind!\">>";
    echo('<div onclick="foo(\'' . addslashes(htmlspecialchars($stuff)) . '\')">Click me</div>');
?>
<script>
function foo(stuff) {
    alert(stuff);
} 
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I hope you ment - onclick="postMeet(\'". htmlspecialchars($name) ."\')"

Comment: @devdRew: No, I didn't, because he's using `'`, not `"`, to quote the string passed to `echo`. I did, however, miss out a couple `'` characters, so thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo('
 <li>
 <a href="#" onclick="window.open(\'http://www.facebook.com/' . $id . '\')">
 <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/' . $id . '/picture?type=square" alt="' . $name . '">'. $name . '
</a>
<form>
<input type="button" value="Meet" onclick="postMeet(. $name.)"/>
</form>
</li>');
}
```

The wrong part is . $name., . $name . change to \'' . $name . '\' so that should be

```
echo('
 <li>
 <a href="#" onclick="window.open(\'http://www.facebook.com/' . $id . '\')">
 <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/' . $id . '/picture?type=square" alt="' . $name . '">'. $name . '
</a>
<form>
<input type="button" value="Meet" onclick="postMeet(\'' . htmlspecialchars($name) . '\')"/>
</form>
</li>');
}
```

Thats why

```
$name = 'Andrew';
$var = '$name'; // outputs '$name';
$var = "$name"; // outputs 'Andrew';
```

Comment: ...and if `$name` contains a `'`? Or a `"`?

Comment: then htmlspecialchars($name), but the main question I think is how to put VALUE of var into string :)

Comment: If you just say "put quotes around it" knowing full well that that's not going to be the whole answer in the general case, you're just setting the questioner up for trouble later on.

Comment: In general? You would have to escape it using htmlspecialchars.
**Edit**: replaced addslashes with htmlspecialchars.

Comment: Question is strongly exact... how to path var into function. Here is the answer. I don't think I should give a full FAQ for PHP to explain how to path variable. Is it OK?

Comment: @Wing There is much more cases there, I think.

Comment: @devdRew: ***Inside*** an HTML attribute. Why answer half the question? Names can readily contain `'` (Dutch names in particular).

Comment: Well, yeah. So there must be htmlspecialchars, I didn't thought about Dutch names. My misstake.

Comment: @devdRew: And here I was showing my PHP ignorance and also not quite paying enough attention: `htmlspecialchars` doesn't encode `'` as `&apos;` and even if it did, technically that would result in invalid JavaScript (because the markup `onclick="postMeet('Gerard &apos;t Hooft')"` *should* result in the browser passing the string `postMeet('Gerard 't Hooft')` to the JavaScript interpreter, which is a syntax error. We need both `addslashes` and `htmlspecialchars`. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

mention

onclick="postMeet(. $name.)"/>

As 
onclick="postMeet('.$name.')"/>

Comment: Works perfectly with:
    \''. htmlspecialchars($name) .'\'
Thanks everyone!